# Is it possible to pass a single argument into two different parameters inside of a Python function?

Tags: python

As the the title explains, I was wondering whether it was possible to pass a single argument into two different parameters in a Python function when calling it. In example:

```
def function(a, b):

    return a + b


# The idea being that both a and b are assigned the value of 3 when the function is called
function(3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `b` a default value. If it contains the default, replace it with `a`.

```
def f(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = a
    return a + b
```

Comment: Or use `*args`... But I guess the question might be about general functions, which are already implemented to take more than one argument.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean, thanks. I should have been more clear with the context of my question. I originally came to this question as I was coding a recursive function and wanted the argument to remain constant throughout the iterations whilst still being the condition that allows the recursion to occur. I'm sure that wasn't a clear explanation but in essence, I was replacing an iterative method for creating a nested list grid with a recursive solution but was not able to keep the amount of elements in the nested list the same as I was reducing that same variable to iterate that many times.

Comment: So you want to specify the second argument explicitly in the recursive calls, but leave it out in the initial call, right? That should work with my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generalize and allow any quantity of `args`.

```
>>> def sumify(*args):
...     return sum(args)
... 
>>> sumify(1,2,3)
6
>>> sumify(1)
1
>>> sumify()
0
```